# Creating and Receiving Electromagnetic Field with RaspberryPi

Tags: arduino, frequency, raspberry-pi, electromagnetic

I am trying to make a basic HLEM (Horizontal Loop Electromagnetic) device for my undergraduate thesis but I haven't started yet, just researching that can I build it myself without sufficient help. I am geophysical engineering student and also a programmer but I have limited knowledge on electronics.

I have 2 loops. First one transmitter and second one receiver. Transmitter should create 2kHz and 6kHz electromagnetic fields at the same time. And receiver can capture primary and secondary fields and record it.

Can I build it with Raspberrypi with/or Arduino with basic circuit boards and modules that can I buy from the internet? or why I can't?

Thanks

[image: Generalized picture of electromagnetic induction prospecting]

**More information:** http://www.epa.gov/esd/cmb/GeophysicsWebsite/pages/reference/methods/Surface_Geophysical_Methods/Electromagnetic_Methods/Frequency_Domain_Electromagnetic_Methods.htm

**Sample Loop :**

[image: Sample loop]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Transmitting and receiving themselves have nothing to do with microcomputers themselves. You can use a sine wave generator, an acoustic power amplifier which can produce high enough output voltage and current to drive your transmitter loop, a microphone amplifier designed for an electrodynamic microphone (which you may need or not depending on your reciever loop sensitivity), and something to process the captured signal.

You do not describe what kind of processing you are going to do, but a ready-made microcomputer like Raspberry Pi could be a good solution as a processing device if you are not much familiar with electronics and if its cost, weight and power consumption is appropriate for you. If so, it's also possible to use it as a software sine wave generator which will also be easier to reconfigure than a purely electronic one.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can.  There's no reason you can't do what you are suggesting, but as Chuck said you will run into some issues.

The biggest one I see is probably transmitting power.  You can only draw ~250 mA from the Arduino, so you'll have to overcome that limitation somehow (shouldn't be too bad).

The other issue is the stability of the transmitter waveform.  Most systems have a bucking coil (the GEM2 is an example; have a look for some papers, I think maybe by Fitterman, about the use of the Qcoil) about 1/3 of the way between the transmitter and receiver.  Without that, any system drift in both time and amplitude will be difficult to account for.

I have no idea how accurate the timing or even what the digitization rate is on an Arduino.  Ideally you'd like to have several frequencies between say a few hundred Hz and maybe 50-100 kHz (if you were building a proper field instrument), but I think one frequency wherever you can get it as a proof of concept would still be impressive if it works.

There are a ton more issues I'm sure you'll run into, but these are the biggies I think.  I think Chuck has a great idea--start with a VLF receiver.  Get that working, and then you can use that as the receiver for your FEM system.

Your system will drift, and drift badly, I'm almost certain (even the commercial ones do).  Don't be discouraged.  If you can repeat measurements over the same spot, or even better construct yourself a calibration coil you can walk over, then you can characterize your drift and all will be right with the world.

I would LOVE to hear how this project goes.  Kudos to you for attempting this.  Please keep us updated and let us know if we can help.

Andy (research geophysicist at the USGS and daily FEM instrument user)

Comment: (I didn't fully read your question to see that you had 2 frequencies planned.  My apologies.)

Comment: Hi, thank you for your comments. I am still researching, when I find something, I'll share with you, also If I complete this project, I'll create a web site for this project. Thanks

Comment: Great.  Also beware thermal expansion.  It's a bigger effect than most people realize, due to changing both the inductance of the loops, but also the intercoil separation.  The apparent conductivity is inversely proportional to s^2, where s is the coil separation.

Answer (score 1):

You are about to discover why HLEM equipment is as expensive as it is. 
It is very carefully and cleverly made. At Michigan Tech we have an Apex Parametrics
Max Min I and a Geophex GEM-2 and they work very nicely.

You might like to start small. I devised a table top model for HLEM that uses
a signal generator an oscilloscope or DVM and small coils.

The reference is Journal of Geological Education, v50, no 5 p594.
TABLETOP MODELS FOR ELECTRICAL AND ELECTROMAGNETIC GEOPHYSICS
Charles T. Young Department of Geological Engineering and Sciences, Michigan Technological University, Houghton, MI 49931, (906) 487-2072, fax (906) 487-3371, ctyoung@mtu.edu

I can send you a PDF if you want. My email is below.

Actually, I think you would have much better luck trying to emulate a 
VLF receiver such as a Geonics EM-16 or a ABEM Wadi. They are just as useful
as HLEM but would be much simpler to build because they are just receivers.

Chuck Young (Geophysical Engineering Professor Emeritus, Michigan Tech University)

Comment: Within the purpose of the Stack Exchange Q&A, this doesn't really answer the question.